# Edits made to comments do not show up immediately

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I edited a comment I wrote within the 5 minute window. However, main question view does not change to reflect the new changes (even after a refresh).

Oddly, selecting to edit the comment again displays the successfully edited comment in the edit text box.

This could lead to a lot of confusion as to whether the user successfully edited his or her comment.

Comment: Yes, that is a duplicate.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, you can click the big blue button 'That solved my question' you should see at the top of your screen :)